# How to get the connection used as parameter in NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

Weapon is a child object of the player object, the child object Weapon cant be regard as a part of the player object, right? So, I need to use NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority() to give non-player object local authority.

```
public class Weapon: NetworkBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
         // how to get the conn?
         GameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().AssignClientAuthority(conn);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CmdShot();
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdShot()
    {
         // shot...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NetworkIndentity` component must on the root gameobject, and it can only have one in a prefab.

So, only the root gameobject have the `ClientAuthority` to send `Command` to server.The child object under this gameobject has no `ClientAuthority`.

And [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-how-to-allocate-netid-and-how-to-find-object-using-netid.366085/#post-2369963) is more about the `NetworkIndentity`.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you can get the connection using `NetworkClient.connection`. On the server the list of all current active connections are avaiable in `NetworkServer.connections`. Both contain the object `NetworkConnection` which is the one used as a parameter for `AssignClientAuthority`.